App cannot connect to SQL instance though SSMS can
I'm getting the below error message when attempting to connect to an SQL Server hosted on an Azure VM.
Network error code 0x2746 occurred while establishing a connection; the connection has been closed. This may have been caused by client or server login timeout expiration. Time spent during login: total 12 ms, enqueued 0 ms, network writes 0 ms, network reads 0 ms, establishing SSL 12 ms, network reads during SSL 8 ms, network writes during SSL 0 ms, secure calls during SSL 3 ms, enqueued during SSL 0 ms, negotiating SSPI 0 ms, network reads during SSPI 0 ms, network writes during SSPI 0 ms, secure calls during SSPI 0 ms, enqueued during SSPI 0 ms, validating login 0 ms, including user-defined login processing 0 ms.
I can connect to the SQL Server from SSMS hosted on the same server as the app and I'm not getting an error messages in the SQL Server error log so I'm confident the issue is isolated to the app but am a bit stumped.

What is the connection string that the app uses?

There is only time in SSL processing and nothing else, if there are no errors in the errorlog then it's most likely that you're missing proper encryption options in the connection string. Much as JD pointed out, what's the connection string for the app?
